# Splitting a string and picking a value

Tags: python, split

I have string in Python which I am splitting using Split. Then I access its length and want to pick up the 3rd value.

```
Q = S.split('/')
E = = len(Q)
R = Q[E[2]] // ERROR
```

Any idea how can I access the 3rd value after using split ?

Comment: No need for `E`... Just `R = Q[2]`

Comment: You can't index an integer.

Comment: I tried your  method @Jared but it gives me an error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Nick -- Then it's best to see how big your split string is.  Perhaps your string has less than 2 `'/'` in it.

Comment: Suppose my S = Hey/there/you/are and I want to access the third value which is "you" in S! I did split but now how can I access the 3rd Val?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these answers are correct, I just wanted to add a bit of of a break down of what is going wrong with the original question.  When you make the following assignment:

```
E = len(Q)
```

`E` is being set to an integer.  When you attempt to execute this:

```
R = Q[E[2]]
```

When you are actually trying to do is take the second element of the `integer` `E`.  Since `E` isn't an array (the technical error is `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`) this is where the program breaks (actually it would break on `E = = len(Q)` but I'm assuming this is a typo in your question since you point to an error happening after this line).

Answer (score 2):

Your second line is not needed at all. You can do this a few ways

```
Q = S.split('/')
R = Q[2]
```

Another option is:

```
R = S.split('/')[2]
```

Example output:

```
>>> S = "Hey/there/you/are"
>>> Q = S.split('/')
>>> R = Q[2] 
>>> R
'you'
>>> R = S.split('/')[2]
>>> R
'you'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
R = S.split('/')[2]
```

to pick the third value. Usually when you split using `/` it is related to a file path. If this is the case you have the following shortcut:

```
import os
R = os.path.split(path)
```

Comment: That would give the third character, not the third element when split by the '/' character.

Comment: but that's exactly what he wants, the third value in the string

Comment: Your original answer was showing iterating over the string which, while useful, would not be relevant to what the question was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is invalid syntax (`E == len(Q)`)

To access the third value:

```
Q = S.split('/')
R = Q[2]
```

Now you might want to use `len()` to check and make sure the list has an appropriate number of elements first, but `len()` will return an integer which is the length. For example:

```
Q = S.split('/')
if len(Q) >= 3:
    R = Q[2]
else:
    # handle a situation where there aren't enough elements
```

Comment: I would use `try`/`except IndexError` instead of checking the length

Comment: @JonClements good point. If he is making the assumption there should be at least three elements it would make more sense. I suppose I just threw in a misguided attempt to show how len() could be used based on the question itself.

Comment: @GavinH I suppose one could do away with the try/except with the hideous `R, = Q[2:3] or ('',)`

Comment: @JonClements There's a good one. What does the tuple unpacking get you beyond `R = Q[2:3] or ''`?